# Executable named yesod not found on path

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-stack

Getting this issue while trying to run my Yesod application. `stack build` has already been run and gives no output anymore.

```
$ stack exec -- yesod devel
Executable named yesod not found on path: ["path/to/app"]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turns out `yeosd-bin` needs to be compiled separately.

Running `$ stack build yesod-bin` solves the issue.